# K8 Ingress does not have an endpoint

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to make services accessible from outside the K8 cluster using an ingress controller. Following 5.5 from the Kubernetes Cookbook, I ran this manifest:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-public
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /web
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

The Ingress object is visible in the Kubernetes dashboard; but it does not have an assigned endpoint:

[image]

Output of `kubectl get ing`:

```
NAME           HOSTS     ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
nginx-public   *                   80        54m
```

**update**

Running `kubectl describe ingress nginx-public` gives:

```
Name:             nginx-public
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /web   nginx:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:  /
Events:                                  <none>
```

Comment: Which ingress controller are you running? Which platform/cloud provider are you running on?

Comment: You can check the logs of nginx-ingress-controller to see if the ingress is handled by it.

Comment: It is manually installed on azure vm's; how can I check the ingress controller, isn't it stated in the yaml? How can I check the logs of the nginx-ingress-controller?

Comment: @API Check the update on my answer pease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Actually this is  an issue with Kubernetes Dashboard, we have the same issue.</s>

Even if it isn't displayed it doesn't mean your ingress isn't working. First you should check the ingress with kubectl (kubectl describe ingress nginx-public) and verify that the output is smiliar to this:

```
Name:             test-ingress
Namespace:        test
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  test-ssl-secret terminates test.myorg.com
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  test.myorg.com  
                            /   test-service:80 (<none>)
```

Afterwards you should verify your service is reachable via your specified host.

**Update:**

Depending on the service in front of your ingress-controller your service should be reachable via http://{serverip}:{nodeport-http-port}/web in case your service is of type NodePort(you will get 2 external ports in the 30000-39999 range, one is the http port the other the https port) or http://{address-from-external-loadbalancer}/web if the service is of type LoadBalancer.

**2nd-Update**

After some further investigation about the issue i stumbled upon a [bug issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2988) of kubernetes-dashboard stating that it's indeed possible to show the endpoints of ingress. The problem actually isn't caused by the dashboard, but a missing parameter on the ingress deployment.

For nginx-ingress-controller its the following:

[NGINX Ingress CLI arguments](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/)

The missing option is *--publish-service*
If you used helm to deploy the controller you need to add the parameter *--set controller.publishService.enabled=true*